# Using 'find' for recursive search and delete

Tags: find, rm, whitespace

I want to search files having name libre in them & then delete them.
I am half done here & can't find a reliable way to delete files especially when filenames have white spaces in them.

```
find -iname *libre*
```

this will search the files, but let's say a file is 'Libre Office Word' now it has white spaces can you guide how to delete such files too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `-delete` option if your version of find supports it or you can use `rm` in the `-exec` options.

```
find -iname '*libre*' -delete       # GNU find
find -iname '*libre*' -exec rm {} + # POSIX
```

Note that you should quote the pattern. This prevents the shell from expanding it prior to being passed to the find command.

Comment: I'm not sure if OP wants also uppercase letters in the name (by the example given).

Comment: @vonbrand my understanding is the OP wanted "Libre Office Word' to match, but was using some method of deletion (such as xargs or a for loop) that broke on files with spaces.

Comment: @jordanm yes you identified my real position. OK so the -delete flag worked even for whitesapces. How can I also pass a file extension to this search I mean search for *libre* & *.desktop

Comment: `-iname` is not POSIX. `-delete` is not POSIX but is not exclusive to GNU `find`.

Comment: Also note that `-delete` deletes (non-empty) directories, while `rm` wouldn't. `-delete` (both with GNU and FreeBSD finds at least) implies `-depth`.